# I would like to add a column to my table showing the week number in the data, based on the data time on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, customization, week-number

I have a date field in a table on Postgresql. I would like to add another column showing the week number of each date. But the weeks should be based on the time interval of the data. I mean, if the data starts from '2018-05-02' the Week1 should be covering the days between '2018-05-02' and '2018-05-08'.

date_trunc function does not work for this case.

Comment: What do you mean with "Week1"? Is the first week the week of the first date? When starts the count?

Comment: West European week numbers? Or US? (big difference)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to calculate this by subtracting the minimum date and extracting the number of days:

```
create table test (a timestamp);
insert into test values ('2019-01-01T00:00:00');
insert into test values ('2019-02-01T00:00:00');

select a, floor(extract(days from (a - (select min(a) from test)))/7) as week
FROM test;
          a          | week
---------------------+------
 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |    0
 2019-02-01 00:00:00 |    4

insert into test values ('2018-01-01T00:00:00');
select a, floor(extract(days from (a - (select min(a) from test)))/7) as week
FROM test;
          a          | week
---------------------+------
 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |   52
 2019-02-01 00:00:00 |   56
 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |    0
(3 rows)
```